# Endomorphism Ring - Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an Abelian group. We may consider the group $\big(\operatorname{End}(G), +\big)$. Next we may endow $\operatorname{End}(G)$ with the composition of functions to make it a ring. Anyway, it seems to me that there are two different ways in which this can be done. One can think of the composition of two endomorphisms in this way: $(\phi\cdot \psi)(g):=\psi\big(\phi(g)\big)$, or one may also think to put $(\phi\cdot \psi)(g):=\phi\big(\psi(g)\big)$. In any case $\big(\operatorname{End}(G), +, \cdot\big)$ is a ring.

Are these two rings isomorphic?

If not, which is the correct definition of "endomorphism ring" of $G$?

Is there any example which proves that, in general, they are not isomorphic?

Comment: They are [antiisomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiisomorphism).

Comment: Note that the automorphism ring (the subring of all isomorphisms) *is* isomorphic to the corresponding ring with opposite composition because $\phi^{-1}\circ \psi^{-1} = (\psi \circ \phi)^{-1}$ so the map $\phi \mapsto \phi^{-1}$ would be the isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two rings are not isomorphic, they are [antiisomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiisomorphism). The convention is that we write $\varphi\circ \psi$ for multiplication in this ring. It is defined as $$(\varphi\circ\psi)(g)=\varphi\big(\psi(g)\big).$$

For an example showing that the rings are not generally isomorphic I would like to refer to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/64379/49910) on MO.

Comment: In fact, the map $M\mapsto M^T$ is an isomorphism from the endomorphism ring on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to the ring with the opposite composition (where here a matrix $M$ represents an endomorphism in the obvious way).

Comment: @W4cc0 I found an example. (Truth be told I did not yet find the time to check all the details of the answer myself, but it seems very reliable.)

Comment: Ok, I've checked all the calculations of the example and, except from the fact that equation (2) is wrong (or apparently is), the example works! Thanks!